# MFnMesh allIntersections returning wrong results

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I'm trying to use Maya's api to test if a point is inside a certain mesh by shooting a ray and seeing how many faces it hits. I'm doing this with `MFnMesh.allIntersections`. The issue I'm coming up with is that sometimes the method returns results that I don't expect and that don't make sense! For example, I'm testing a point at the bottom of a sphere with its normal like so:

[image: Example]

Like in the image, it should hit 2 points, yet for some reason it says it hits 3 instead!
Why is this happening? I'm including code that should replicate this example:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya


cmds.file(new=True, force=True)

cmds.polyCube(subdivisionsWidth=4, subdivisionsHeight=4, subdivisionsDepth=4)
cmds.setAttr("pCube1.translate", 0, 0.236, 0)

cmds.polySphere(subdivisionsAxis=25, subdivisionsHeight=25)
cmds.setAttr("pSphere1.translate", 0, 2, 0)

dag_path = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
sel = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
sel.add("pCube1")
sel.getDagPath(0, dag_path)

mfn_mesh = OpenMaya.MFnMesh(dag_path)

hit_points = OpenMaya.MFloatPointArray()
hit_ray_params = OpenMaya.MFloatArray()
hit_faces = OpenMaya.MIntArray()

has_int = mfn_mesh.allIntersections(
    OpenMaya.MFloatPoint(0, 1, 0), # Should match pSphere1.vtx[600]'s world position
    OpenMaya.MFloatVector(1.1905393115796414e-08, -1.0, 1.8535209278525144e-07), # Should match pSphere1.vtx[600]'s normal
    None,
    None,
    False,
    OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld,
    999999,
    False,
    mfn_mesh.autoUniformGridParams(),
    False,
    hit_points,
    hit_ray_params,
    hit_faces,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    0.0001
)

print hit_points.length() # Should return 2 but returns 3!!!
```

Comment: for me if I try your code, it print 4. it return both points twice. If I  change direction to (0, -1, 0), it return only the two points once. Im not sure why :|

Comment: My deformer is outputting those normal values to me for that vertex, though I don't see why they would be messing it up, but they do! This is causing some crazy popping at unexpecting times.

Comment: if i remove the raycast acceleration, it gives a proper result.

Comment: I noticed that it still gives wrong results in other positions when acceleration is removed, so there's still something going on. I noticed this only happens when both objects are directly on top of each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out when `MFnMesh.allIntersections` intersects exactly against an edge or vertex, instead of returning one hit point it'll return multiple, so it's possible to get many hits at the same position. I played around with the method's tolerance value and it had no effect. So instead when a hit occurs I can use `MFloatVector.isEquivalent` and trim out any positions that are almost identical. Now I'm getting the expected output.

Comment: interesting and weird, autodesk has his way to drive us nuts :|

Comment: instead of maya.OpenMaya (old), use maya.api.OpenMaya (new)